# Disappearing buttons and labels in SpriteKit swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm making simple math game with swift 3 in SpriteKit, its my second project in SpriteKit so be patient. I have weird problem because sometimes my app works but sometimes my labels and objects despair. In my app, the orange circle on the top is falling down with randomized number in label, when user click one of the buttons below red line, number in label is dividing by the number which is on a button, when number that is dividing is equal to 1 games should stop,and it might pop up a label with text "You win!".(photo)

[[image]]

If the falling ball touch the red line before the number will be equal 1 game should stop and it might pop up a label with text "Game over".(photo)

[image]

Sometimes one of the labels disappears (photo 1) and (photo 2)

[image]
[image]

Sometimes number on falling ball disappear after dividing (photo)

[image: disappearing label]

or at the start of a game. I don't know why this is happening but sometimes it works perfectly.

My GameScene code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


enum gametype {
    case game
    case wait
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    print("test1")
    koniec = self.childNode(withName: "gameover") as! SKLabelNode
    ball = self.childNode(withName: "pilka") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball.position.y = view.frame.height/2 - 20
    numberinball = self.childNode(withName: "liczba") as! SKLabelNode
    numberinball.position.x = ball.position.x
    numberinball.position.y = (ball.position.y) - 14
    random()
    ball.alpha = 1
    numberinball.alpha = 1
    koniec.alpha = 0
    button2 = self.childNode(withName: "2") as! SKSpriteNode
    button3 = self.childNode(withName: "3") as! SKSpriteNode
    button4 = self.childNode(withName: "4") as! SKSpriteNode
    button5 = self.childNode(withName: "5") as! SKSpriteNode
    button6 = self.childNode(withName: "6") as! SKSpriteNode
    button7 = self.childNode(withName: "7") as! SKSpriteNode
    button8 = self.childNode(withName: "8") as! SKSpriteNode
    button9 = self.childNode(withName: "9") as! SKSpriteNode
    button2.alpha = 1
    button3.alpha = 1
    button4.alpha = 1
    button5.alpha = 1
    button6.alpha = 1
    button7.alpha = 1
    button8.alpha = 1
    button9.alpha = 1
    gamedidstart1 = .game
}


//Variables

var button2 = SKSpriteNode()
var button3 = SKSpriteNode()
var button4 = SKSpriteNode()
var button5 = SKSpriteNode()
var button6 = SKSpriteNode()
var button7 = SKSpriteNode()
var button8 = SKSpriteNode()
var button9 = SKSpriteNode()

var ball = SKSpriteNode()

var numberinball = SKLabelNode()
var koniec = SKLabelNode()

var liczba = Int()
var numberingame = 0

var gamedidstart1:gametype = .game

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        print(location)

        if gamedidstart1 == .game {
            if button2.contains(location) && numberingame % 2 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/2
                print("number has been divided by 2")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button3.contains(location) && numberingame % 3 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/3
                print("number has been divided by 3")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button4.contains(location) && numberingame % 4 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/4
                print("number has been divided by 4")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button5.contains(location) && numberingame % 5 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/5
                print("number has been divided by 5")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
                print(numberinball.alpha)
            }else if button6.contains(location) && numberingame % 6 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/6
                print("number has been divided by 6")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button7.contains(location) && numberingame % 7 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/7
                print("number has been divided by 7")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button8.contains(location) && numberingame % 8 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/8
                print("number has been divided by 8")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }else if button9.contains(location) && numberingame % 9 == 0 {
                numberingame = numberingame/9
                print("number has been divided by 9")
                numberinball.alpha = 1
                numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
            }
            print(numberingame)
            print(numberinball.alpha)
        }//numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
    }
}


//Movng the ball
func ballpos() {
    ball.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: (ball.position.y) - 30, duration: 1))
    numberinball.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: (numberinball.position.y) - 30, duration: 1))
}

//Randomizing number

func random() {

    var randomized = Int()

    repeat{
        randomized = Int(arc4random_uniform(100)+1)
        print("randomized liczba to: \(randomized)")
    }while sprawdz(Liczba: randomized) || randomized == 1
    numberingame = randomized
    numberinball.text = String(numberingame)
    print("liczba w labelu zostaje ustawiona na: \(randomized)")
}



//Checking if number is divided by 2,3 or 5

func sprawdz(Liczba:Int) ->Bool {

    var geted = Liczba
    print("liczba przyjęta to:\(geted)")
    while true {
        if geted % 2 == 0 && geted != 1{
            geted = geted/2
            print("gate if geted % 2 == 0 && geted != 1 positive, liczba po podziale to: \(geted)")
        }else if  geted == 1 {
            print("number is equal to one after while block for number two, number: \(geted)")
            return false
        }else if geted < 10 {
            print("number is lower than ten so its returning")
            return false
        }else {
            print("gate for loop while for number two negative")
            break
        }
    }

    while true {
        if geted % 3 == 0 && geted != 1{
            geted = geted/3
            print("gate if geted % 3 == 0 && geted != 1 positive, number after dividing: \(geted)")
        }else if  geted == 1 {
            print("number is equal to one after while block for number three, number: \(geted)")
            return false
        }else if geted < 10 {
            print("number is lower than 10: \(geted) so it is returned")
            return false
        }else {
            print("gate for loop while for number three negative")
            break
        }
    }

    while true {
        if geted % 5 == 0 && geted != 1{
            geted = geted/5
            print("gate % 5 == 0 && geted != 1 positive, number after dividing: \(geted)")
        }else if  geted == 1 {
            print("number is equal one after while block for number five: \(geted)")
            return false
        }else if geted < 10 {
            print("number is lower than 10 \(geted) so it is returned")
            return false
        }else {
            print("gate for loop while for number five negative")
            break
        }
    }
    return true
}



override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


    if gamedidstart1 == .game {
        if ball.position.y <= koniec.position.y{
            koniec.alpha = 1
            koniec.text = "Game Over"
            ball.removeAllActions()
            ball.alpha = 0
            numberinball.alpha = 1
            numberinball.removeAllActions()
            gamedidstart1 = .wait
            //print(numberinball.alpha)
            //print(numberinball.color!)
        }else {
            ballpos()
            //print(numberinball.alpha)
            //print(numberinball.color!)
        }
        if numberingame == 1 {
            ball.removeAllActions()
            ball.alpha = 1
            numberinball.removeAllActions()
            numberinball.alpha = 1
            koniec.alpha = 1
            koniec.text = "You Win!"
            gamedidstart1 = .wait
            //print(numberinball.alpha)
            //print(numberinball.color!)
        }
    }
    //numberinball.fontColor = UIColor.white


}
```

}

PS. I set alpha of buttons and labels to be sure that they aren't missing because they have alpha = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zPosition` of nodes in spritekit is a nightmare. Unless it is specifically set, nodes with the same zPosition can end up in front or behind each other randomly.

I suggest making sure that nodes that need to appear in front have larger `zPosition`s than what you wish to have in the background.

Comment: Nodes with the same `zPosition` is estabilished by the "addChild" order in your code: the last is in front of all.